# How to parse strings into numericals for a summation function?

Tags: python

I want to write a summation function, but can't figure out how I would parse the bottom expression and right expression.

```py
def summation(count: int, bottom_var: str, espression: str):
    out = 0
    
    # parse bottom_var into a variable and it's value
    value = ···
    var_name = ···
    expression.replace(var_name, value)
    ···
```

I want you to be able to use the inputs the same way as in normal sigma notation, as in `bottom_var` is `'n=13'`, not `'13'`.

You enter an assignment for `bottom_var`, and an expression using the variable defined in `bottom_var` in `expression`.

Example:

```py
summation(4, 'x=1', 'x+1')
```

*(would return 14, as 2+3+4+5=14)*

Comment: If `x=1` then `x+1` equals `2`, not `5`...

Comment: This is not clear from the question and is not reflected in the expected answer... What if `x=2`? Would it be `2+1+1+1+1`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo No. But I did mess up my answer. I will go re-write it.

Comment: I think your question is not very clear. I'm well aware of sigma notation and only now understood what you mean...

Comment: @Tomerikoo What about it is unclear?

Comment: I actually think you should read about it, because if I'm understanding correctly, if the bottom of the sigma is `x=1`, the upper count is `4` and the expression is `x+1` than the sigma expands to `(1+1)+(2+1)+(3+1)+(4+1)` and not `1+1+1+1`

Comment: haha are you serious?! You just changed it to the correct output and ask me what is not clear?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh. I did not realize that was what was unclear. I wrote that post at 3a.m. and forgot how math works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse the `bottom_var` to get the symbol and starting value:

```py
var, value = bottom_var.split('=')
var = var.strip()
value = eval(value)
```

Using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) we get the two parts of the equal sign easily. Using [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) we even allow any number of spaces, like `x =  1`.

Then, we want to create a loop from the starting value to `count`:

```py
for i in range(value, count+1):
    ...
```

Lastly, we want to use the loop to sum the `expression` when each time the symbol is replaced with the current iteration's value. All in all:

```py
def summation(count: int, bottom_var: str, expression: str):
    var, value = bottom_var.split('=')
    var = var.strip()
    value = eval(value)
    res = 0
    for i in range(value, count+1):
        res += eval(expression.replace(var, str(i)))

    return res
```

For example:

```
>>> summation(4, 'x=1', 'x+1')
14
```

---

Proposing the code in this answer, I feel the need to ask you to read about [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) and please make sure that it is OK for your application. Notice that depending on the context of the use of your code, using `eval` can be quite dangerous and lead to bad outcomes.

Comment: This nearly works properly, but does not support a more complex variable definition. The only method I know of to have this work is to replace `value = int(value)` with `value = int(eval(value))`, so I did so. It also does not allow floating point numbers, as they are being converted to an integer, but I can't see that being fixable with your method.

Comment: Sounds good, but do you mean something like `x=2z`? That is not "evaluateable". Maybe `x=2*z`. And still `z` has to be an integer and the result needs to be smaller than the `count`

Comment: I don't think floats are acceptable with sigma notation...

Comment: I fixed the first thing you mentioned (possible now to do `x=2*z`), but as to your second problem it's not applicable. The bottom and top values have to be integers. They represent an index...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation

Comment: I realize this is quite old now, but I am having another issue, which may require for a change. I need the `eval()` statement to return type `decimal.Decimal`. How might this be done?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it:

```
def summation(count,bottom_var,expression):
    begin = False
    x = ""
    
    v = ""
    
    for char in bottom_var:
        if begin:
            x += char
    
        if char == "=":
            begin = True
    
        if begin == False:
            v += char
    
    x = int(x)
    
    expression = expression.replace(v,str("x"))
    
    print(expression)
    
    for n in range(count):
        x = eval(expression)
    
summation(4,"d=152",'d+145*2')
```

Comment: The above just prints `x+145*2`... Not sure if this is the expected output

Comment: @Tomerikoo i forgot to add return x in the end, it returns the desired output

Answer (score -1):

There are some built-in function in python which execute code from `text`  or `str` which are `exec()` and `eval()` function.

for example :

```
>>> exec('n=13')
>>> print(n)
13
>>> eval('n+1')
14
```

you can use this in your code.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, reread my EDIT.